# Spring Integration JMS Outbound adapter transaction control

Tags: spring, spring-integration, jms, spring-jms

in order to reach high performance production of messages with jms with transactions enabled, one needs to control the amount of messages being sent on each transaction, the larger the number the higher the performance are,

is it possible to control transactions in such a way using spring integration ?

one might suggest using an aggregator, but that defeats the purpose because i dont want to have one message containing X smaller messages on the queue, but actually X messages on my queue..

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of your setup, but I'd bump up the concurrent consumers on the source than try to tweak the outbound adapter. What kind of data source is pumping in this volume of data ?  From my experience, usually the producer lags behind the publisher - unless both are JMS / messaging resources - like in the case of a bridge. In which case you will mostly see a significant improvement by bumping up the concurrent consumers, because you are dedicating n threads to receive messages and process them in parallel, and each thread will be running in its own "transaction environment".

It's also worthwhile to note that JMS does **not** specify a transport mechanism, and its unto the broker to choose the transport. If you are using activemq you can try experimenting with open wire vs amqp and see if you get the desired throughput.